# How to add social media icon on new user confirmation email as a hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, html, web, vs-web-site-project, confirmation-email

I want to add social media icon on my new user confirmation email like-
[Image of how the confirmation email should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vDvz.png)

It is working perfectly on my browser, but when I am implementing this code for my website and when a user is registering in my website, they are receiving email look like(without showing email icon, but it is working as a hyperlink when they click on empty space of the icon place)--
[Image of how user is seeing confirmation email without icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXGFz.png)

The code I have used---

```html
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
     
  <style>
    body
    {
      width:60%;
      height:auto;
      margin-left:auto;
      margin-right:auto;
    }
.wrapper {
          
          height:auto;
          width:60%;
          margin:50px;
          padding: 20px;
          color: #444;
          font-size: 1.3em;
          background: #F5F5F5;
          border:5px solid #FFFAFA;
        }
        .wrapper .inner
        {
         
          background:white;
          padding:50px;
        }
        img
        {
             display: block;
              margin-left: auto;
             margin-right: auto;
            
      
            
        }
        #p1 {
          background:#592f80;
          text-decoration: none;
          padding:15px;
          border-radius: 5px;
          color: #fff;
                    }
               .icon_t
            {
           
         display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
 
  width:100%;

   


 
  
}
.icon_t ul {
     margin-top:0.5px;    
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;




}


.icon_t ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #5F9EA0;
    text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  line-height:60px;
  background: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;

  }

.icon_t ul li a:hover{
     background:none;
     color:purple;
    
    
}
      </style>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="inner">
        <h2>Hi,</h2>
        <img src="company_logo2.png" alt="our company logo">
        <p>Thank you for signing up on our site. Please click on the link below to verify your account.</p>
        <a id="p1" href=" ******** ">Verify Email!</a>
        <p>If you receive this email by mistake,then simply ignore this email.You won't be verified if you don't click the button above.</p>
      </div>
       <div class="icon_t"> 
      <ul>
<li><a href="https://www.facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.instagram.com"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="https://bd.linkedin.com/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="https://youtube.com/"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
    </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

I have used ******* here, instead of original 'href' value for security purposes.
So my question is "Here also in code snippet I am seeing social icon but why user is not showing social media icon when they are getting confirmation email after register as a new user for my website?"

Comment: Is font awesome loading on your live site?

Comment: @GetSet Yes, font awesome is loading perfectly on other pages of my live site ,but I am facing problem just here.

Comment: What happens when you remove `class="icon_t"`?

Comment: @GetSet Nothing is happened after removing class="icon_t"

Comment: Font awesome seems as its not loading correctly. You can check console/dev tools to see if thats the case.

Comment: Also try clearing your browser cache before testing live

Comment: @GetSet I checked console ,Font awesome loading can be a reason for this problem, if so then what can be the alternation of Font awesome ?

Comment: If its loading locally, but not on Live deployment, then you check console/dev tools to see if its getting blocked. Could be a `http` site accessing `https` resources. Doubt that tho.